# Paginar consulta no laravel usando DB::table

Tags: laravel

```
$role = $request->id_cliente;
        $data_inicial = $request->data_inicial;
        $data_final = $request->data_final;
        $vendasCliente = DB::table('venda')
                        ->join('cliente', 'cliente.id_cliente', '=', 'venda.id_cliente')
                        ->select('cliente.nome', 'venda.tipo_pagamento', 'venda.data_hora', 'venda.total_venda')
                        ->where('data_hora' ,'>=' , $data_inicial)
                        ->where('data_hora' ,'<=' , $data_final)
                        ->when($role, function ($query, $role) {
                            return $query->where('venda.id_cliente', $role);
                        })
                        ->paginate(3);

        return response()->json($vendasCliente);
```

Tenho a consulta acima no laravel porém não consigo paginar o resultado dessa query...se eu usar o get() ele me traz o retorno da consulta sem paginação e seu coloco esse paginate na consulta ele não me traz os registros..

Comment: Tente usar `simplePaginate()` em vez de `paginate()`

Comment: paginate() retorna algum erro ou simplesmente retorna vazio?